# Differentiation of a homogeneous function. Application of the chain rule.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ if
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda x) = \lambda^k f(x)\;\;\;\forall \lambda>0 
\end{equation}

I would like to prove Euler's Theorem which states that if $f$ is a function with continuous partial derivatives. Then $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$ if and only if
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)x_i = kf(x)\;\;\;\forall x
\end{equation}

The idea is to fix $x$ and differentiate both sides of the definition with respect to $\lambda$. I'm slightly unsure how to get the first derivative below
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\lambda} f(\lambda x)= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\lambda x)x_i \\
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\lambda^k f(x) = k\lambda^{k-1}f(x)
\end{align}
I know we use the chain rule but I don't understand how. To finish we substitute $\lambda=1$.

I want to use the chain rule from multivariable calculus: let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ and $F=f\circ g$. Then $DF=Df\;Dg$

In this application I've tried letting $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\lambda\rightarrow \lambda x$. So $Df=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)(\lambda x)$ (1 row $n$ column matrix) and $Dg=(x_1,x_2\ldots,x_2)$ ($n$ row 1 column matrix). Thus

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\lambda x)x_i
\end{equation}
Would this be the correct reasoning?